# PYBIND11: Make changes to class object value in another c++ thread when python interpreter is embedded and running in another thread

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, pybind11, python-bindings

I am just printing the value of car1.vehicle_id in python. I want it to print "1234" for the first 2 seconds and then when the value is changes in another thread to " 4543" the change should take effect in python. Is this possible or is there a simple example to help me with this?

**c++**

> ```
> #include <pybind11/embed.h>
> #include <string>
> #include <thread>
> #include <chrono>
> // Define namespace for pybind11
> namespace py = pybind11;
>
> class Vehiclee
> {
> // Access specifier
> public:
> Vehiclee(){};
> ~Vehiclee() {}
> // Data Members
> int vehicle_id;
> std::string vehicle_name;
> std::string vehicle_color;
>
> // Member Functions()
> void printname()
> {
> std::cout << "Vehicle id is: " << vehicle_id;
> std::cout << "Vehicle name is: " << vehicle_name;
> std::cout << "Vehicle color is: " << vehicle_color;
> }
> };
>
> PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE(embeded, m){
>
> py::class_(m, "Vehiclee")
> .def_readonly("vehicle_name", &Vehiclee::vehicle_name)
> .def_readonly("vehicle_color", &Vehiclee::vehicle_color)
> .def_readonly("vehicle_id", &Vehiclee::vehicle_id);
>
> }
> py::scoped_interpreter python{};
> Vehiclee car1;
>
> void threadFunc()
> {
> sleep(2);
> std::cout<<"entering thread";
> car1.vehicle_id = 4543;
> std::cout<<"Modified val in thread";
>
> }
>
> int main() {
> // Initialize the python interpreter
>
> // Import all the functions from scripts by file name in the working directory
> auto simpleFuncs = py::module::import("simpleFuncs");
>
> // Test if C++ objects can be passed into python functions
>
> car1.vehicle_id = 1234;
> std::thread t1(threadFunc);
> simpleFuncs.attr("simplePrint")(car1);
> t1.join();
> return 0;
> }
> ```

**python**

```
>  import time 
>  import importlib 
>  import embeded
>      
>     def simplePrint(argument): 
>           while(1): 
>               importlib.reload(embeded)
>               print(argument.vehicle_id) time.sleep(1)
```

**Current output**

> always 1234

**Required output**

```
1234 (for first 2 secs)
4543 (after 2 secs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the C++ rules for threading. In C++, threads can run far better in parallel than in Python. This is because in C++, threads are by default running entirely separate from each other, whereas Python uses a Global Interpreter Lock which causes a lot of thread synchronization.

So, in this case you do need the threads to synchronize, because the threads share a variable (`car1`). The challenge is that `.def_readonly` hides some boilerplate code which doesn't do synchronization - makes sense, because what object should it use to synchronize?

So what you need to do is make getter and setter methods in `Vehicle`, and add a `std::mutex`. In every getter and every setter, you lock and unlock this mutex. This is easy with a `std::scoped_lock` - this will automatically unlock the mutex when the method returns.

There are other options. For `vehicle_id` you could use a `std::atomic_int`, but you'd probably still need a getter method. I don't think pybind understands atomic variables.